# metpy vertical velocity unit issue

Tags: python, metpy

I'm trying to estimate the vertical wind velocity from vertical pressure velocity. I found metpy.calc.vertical_velocity(omega, pressure, temperature, mixing=0).

https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.vertical_velocity.html

However, there is no documentation on what unit it needs. I gave it Omega in Pa s-1, pressure in Pa, and temperature in K, all in the xarray format. I expect the output to be a xarray too. I got this error: "Cannot convert from 'pascal * second' to 'dimensionless". Any thought why it wants dimensionless variables and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That error comes from a problem parsing the Udunits-formatted unit string "Pa s-1". The default unit-parser in `pint` (the unit library used by MetPy) parses this as: `Pa * s - 1`, which is non-sensical. Luckily, with MetPy 1.0, this should work:

```
import metpy.calc
import xarray as xr

omega = xr.DataArray([5], attrs={'units': 'Pa s-1'})
pressure = xr.DataArray([50000], attrs={'units': 'Pa'})
temperature = xr.DataArray([283], attrs={'units': 'K'})
metpy.calc.vertical_velocity(omega, pressure, temperature, mixing_ratio=0)
```

You can currently install metpy 1.0.0rc1 from pip:

```
pip install --pre metpy
```

or from conda-forge:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/metpy_rc metpy=1.0.0rc1
```